# Regarding installing a project at the client side

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, installation

I made a desktop project using visual studio 2012 and Sqlserver2012

How to make it ready for clients and combine all of the software needed to run the database and crystal report without installing them individually at the client side.

Comment: Create a setup project in the solution

Comment: @PaulZahra Already i create a setup in the solution ,the problem in the database and crystal report do not work at the client site.. What is the software needed to run the database and crystal report at the setup of project

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio Crystal Reports plugin and the built in visual studio sql server?

Comment: @PaulZahra I am using external sqlserver 2012  and crystal report  for visual stouio 2012

Comment: In the solution options, under Prerequisites: are you requiring the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime, the correct SQL Server runtime, the correct framework, etc?

Comment: Also, which architecture do you want to set this up on? Unless they've fixed the bug, you have to install BOTH the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of CR to 64-bit client machines, which requires some tinkering with a bootstrap file.